# Allow apache user to connect to mysql via auth socket

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I have the following stack:

- apache
- php-fpm
- mysql
- several instances of WordPress

I want to use unix_socket for mysql authentication. I created a linux user for each mysql user so that they can access their DB. For example:

I have a WP blog `foo.com` and I created a user `foo_com` and a db user `foo_com` and a database `foo_com`. If I `su foo_com` I can connect to the db (`mysql foo_com`) but I can't connect to it if I try to connect as root with `mysql -u foo_com foo_com` which I guess is intended because that's how unix_socket works.

When a user goes to www.foo.com the apache will try to serve the WordPress blog. It will try to connect to mysql (with credentials defined in wp-config.php) but because `wwwrun` user is running the apache we will see database auth error.

So my question: How can I run apache and also use unix_socket in WordPress settings (assuming I run several instances of WP)?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this with php-fpm.

What you need is the following. In apache you need to define proxy for php files:

```
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/phpfpm/foo_com.sock"
    </If>
  </FilesMatch>
```

in php-fpm config you need to define (example for foo.com site):

```
[foo_com]
group = wwwrun
listen = /run/phpfpm/foo_com.sock
listen.group = wwwrun
listen.owner = wwwrun
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 32
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.start_servers = 2
user = wp-foo_com
```

And then in mysql you need to have `wp-foo_com` user that has permissions for e.g. `foo_com` database.

In wp-config.php you replace `define( 'DB_HOST', '120.0.0.1' );` with `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' );` assuming `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is the path to mysql socket.

Why does this work? Because when requests comes in for any php file it will get passed to php-fpm (by apache) and then php-fpm executes that code as a user defined in the config above (in our example it was `wp-foo_com` user).

If anyone is on nixos you can just use this config:

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:
let
  domain = "foo.com";
  normalizedDomain = "foo_com";

  user = "wp-${normalizedDomain}";
  group = config.services.httpd.group;
in {

  networking.firewall.enable = true;
  networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 ];

  services.mysql.package = pkgs.mysql;
  services.mysql.enable = true;
  services.mysql.ensureDatabases = [ normalizedDomain ];
  services.mysql.ensureUsers = [{
    name = user;
    ensurePermissions = { "${normalizedDomain}.*" = "ALL PRIVILEGES"; };
  }];

  users.users.${user}.group = group;
  services.phpfpm.pools."${normalizedDomain}" = {
    inherit user group;
    phpPackage = pkgs.php;
    settings = {
      "pm" = "dynamic";
      "pm.max_children" = 32;
      "pm.max_requests" = 500;
      "pm.max_spare_servers" = 4;
      "pm.min_spare_servers" = 2;
      "pm.start_servers" = 2;
      "listen.owner" = config.services.httpd.user;
      "listen.group" = config.services.httpd.group;
    };
  };

  services.httpd = {
    enable = true;
    enablePHP = true;
    extraModules = [ "proxy_fcgi" ];

    virtualHosts."${normalizedDomain}" = {
      adminAddr = "admin@localhost";
      serverAliases = [ domain "www.${domain}" ];
      documentRoot = "/var/www/${normalizedDomain}/public_html";
      extraConfig = ''
        <Directory "/var/www/${normalizedDomain}/public_html">
          <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
              SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/phpfpm/${normalizedDomain}.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
            </If>
          </FilesMatch>

          # standard wordpress .htaccess contents
          <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
          </IfModule>

          DirectoryIndex index.php
          Require all granted
          Options +FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>

        # https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#securing-wp-config-php
        <Files wp-config.php>
          Require all denied
        </Files>
      '';
    };

  };

  services.httpd.adminAddr = "admin@example.com";
}
```